# How to implement role mutual exclusion in spring security? That is, similar to that in RBAC

Tags: rbac

I want to implement a general security template based on RBAC3. I found something about role inheritance in spring security, but I didn't find something related to role mutual exclusion. So, I want to ask, do I need to implement it myself?

What I think is, as a member of the spring family bucket, it gives examples of User classes, permissions, and role inheritance. Is the example of role mutual exclusion missing?

Comment: I don't know about Spring + RBAC. But if you use a ReBAC solution you could use `role1 but not role2`. https://openfga.dev/docs/configuration-language#the-exclusion-operator